# Can I use "some" as noun?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Is this sentence correct?

> Existing requests are evaluated, some may be rescheduled

I am not sure if I can use "some" this way without repeating the word "requests" from the first sentence.

Comment: Yes, *'some'* can be used in the way it has been used in the sentence *"Existing requests are evaluated, some may be rescheduled"*. This isn't wrong.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138529/can-some-be-a-noun-and-a-subject

Comment: Yes, you can say "some", because it's implied that we're already talking about requests.  The only thing I would change is that this sentence uses what's called a [comma splice](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/34/).  Those are two separate sentences - "existing requests are evaluated" and "some may be rescheduled."  You can't just join them with a comma, because they require a conjunction (like *because* or *although* or a semicolon to go together.

Comment: Comma is always used in my native language to separate sentences unless and/or is used. So this is my often mistake. How would correct sentence look?

Comment: @LeosLiterak - In English, it would be phrased "Existing requests are evaluated, **and** some may be rescheduled" or "Existing requests are evaluated, **although** some may be rescheduled" or maybe even "Existing requests are evaluated, **because** some may be rescheduled."  It all depends on exactly what you want to say, but you have to have *some* word connecting the two sentences.  If you don't want to have any conjunction, you can use a semicolon like "Existing requests are evaluated; some may be rescheduled", which is how we join unrelated sentences in English.

Comment: The rescheduling may be consequence of the evaluation.

Comment: Commas are used more often nowadays where once a semi-colon was required, Leos, so your original sentence is informal in form.  But only pedants would claims it's *wrong*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Some* works as a determiner and pronoun (not a noun technically), so you can use it either way.

> Existing requests are evaluated, some may be rescheduled
>
> Existing requests are evaluated, some requests may be rescheduled

Comment: Isn't **as a determiner or a pronoun** the right expression instead of **as a determiner and pronoun** in the first sentence of your answer?